# How do you use googles python api mocks?

Tags: python, google-api, python-unittest, google-api-python-client, python-unittest.mock

I need a bit of help using google's api mocks. I am new to using mocks and google's api.
[Here is the api mock](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/mocks.html)

Here is my code I want to test:

```
#add_entry_to_calendar.py
#...
try:
    service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=delegated_credentials)
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId=calendarID, body=entry).execute()
#handle exceptions


#test_add_entry_to_calendar.py
@patch("add_entry_to_calendar.build")
def test_add_entry_to_calendar_400(self, mock_build):
    
    http = HttpMock('tests/config-test.json', {'status' : '400'})
    service = mock_build("calendar", "v3", http=http)

    self.assertEqual(add_entry_to_calendar({"A":"B"}), None)
```

add_entry_to_calendar is getting the mock object when I run my test.

My question - How do I get add_entry_to_calender to use the HttpMock object that I created in test_add_entry_to_calendar? I need the mock object that is created to ".execute()" with my "HttpMock" that i created in the test as a parameter.

Comment: Does the library throw `JsonRejectedError`? Usually, you catch `HttpError` in which case you'd be looking for 400. Or, you can use [`api_core.exceptions`](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/exceptions.html).

Comment: You will need to use the `HttpMock` that you're creating in the second code block as the HTTP client in the first code block otherwise, you're just using the production service.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks, this got me on the right path.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm pleased to hear that it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError    
except HttpError as google_e:
        response = json.loads(google_e.content)
        
        response_header_code = response.get("error").get("code")
        response_header_message = response.get("error").get("message")
        response_string = F"{response_header_code} {response_header_message} {response.get('error').get('errors')[0]}"

        if response_header_code == 400:
            logger.warning(F"Failed to add entry to calendar. Missing or invalid field parameter in the request. {response_string}")
```

Throw an HttpError and then look for the error code.